# Rendered button size is tiny

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below code,

```
<head>
        <title>Intro</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.3.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery('#button1').click(function(){
                    alert('Button clicked');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" id="button1" value="Click Me"></button>
    </body>
```

---

`button1` size looks tiny on rendering.

*firefox 45* and *chrome 47* render the tiny size button.

How do I resolve this error?

*Note: `window.jQuery` is created*

Comment: how about using css?

Answer (score 3):

The button is empty, put the text you want to display on the button inside the button tag

```
<button type="button" id="button1">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: I gave the `value` as "Click Me". In submit type buttons, value reflects the rendering text in the button

Comment: You mean in submit type `<input>`s

Answer (score 0):

First off, set the text of the button:

`<button type="button" id="button1">Click Me</button>`

If the automatic size from this is not enough, set explicit css, for example:

```
#button1{
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
}
```